# I am having a problem with this date format change

Tags: teradata

I need help with this Teradata date format change

I have tried multiple queries and date formats and nothing seems to work

This was what I tried originally:

'''Teradata
select  distinct concat(trim(EXTRACT(month FROM(rqst.admt_dt))), '/1/', trim(EXTRACT(year FROM(rqst.admt_dt)))) as MonYr
'''

When I create a volatile table with this it makes the datatype varchar(25) and I want the datatype as a date. I tried multiple cast date formats but none of the code was accurate. I decided to do this instead:

'''Teradata
select distinct rqst.admt_dt as MonYr
'''

After I run through all my scripts I end up with the final table and the MonYr is a date but I need to change any days that are not 01 to 01. Examples of the dates I end up with are:

6/02/2018
6/15/2018
6/22/2018

I tried this code to modify the DD to 01

'''Teradata
update dl_aa_tm_oprpt_s.TinaPAVDrop
set monyr = date format 'mm/01/yyyy'
'''

That does not work either. I am at a loss as to how to remedy this issue

Comment: So you want to take a date and replace it with the first day of the month and year?

Comment: I want to take 6/02/2018 and make it 6/01/2018. 6/15/2018 and make that 6/01/2018. 6/22/2018 and make that 6/01/2018. The dates I have in this table range from 6/01/2018 to 6/30/2019. This is a rolling 13 month reporting period so I have a ton of varying dates. I just want to force the DD to be 01 for all the MM and all the YYYY but retain the datatype as a date.

Comment: I tried the original query for the concat trim extract to say leave rqst.dmt_dt as date and then tried the '/1/' as cast('/1/' as date) then rest of code. Teradata did not like that

Answer (score 0):

If you want take a date and get the first day of that month:

```
SELECT
current_date - extract(day from current_date) + 1
```

Just replace current_date with your date column.

Comment: I don't want just the first day of the month. I want to change the rolling 13 months where there could be any DD from 01 to 31 and change it all to 01 but retain the date format

Comment: I guess I could just create another table and do case statements for the rolling 13 months. But that seems like a ton of coding where it should be some sort of simple update query. I would end up with 13 case statements plus pulling in the other columns in the table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You say  you always want DD (day) to be 01, but then you say you don't want the first of the month.

Comment: I have 608 distinct dates between 6/1/2018 and 6/30/2019. I am pulling a rolling 13 months worth of data. These are admission to the hospital dates that is the admt_dt column. I need to change all the DD as in days that are not the first of the month to the first of the month. An example I have 2 through 30 for the month of June in 2018. I need 2 through 30 to be updated to 1 so all I have for June of 2018 is 6/1/2018.

Comment: I even though maybe a case statement so I tried this as an example: ''' select distinct 
case when monyr between 6/1/2018  and 6/30/2018 then cast(6/1/2018 as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy')
when monyr between 7/1/2018 and 7/31/2018 then cast(7/1/2018 as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy')
when monyr between 8/1/2018 and 8/30/2018 then cast(8/1/2018 as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') end as MonYr
from dl_aa_tm_oprpt_s.TinaDate  but that just gives me a ?

Comment: I think I will just have to go back to the original code where it forces a '/1/' at the beginning and then spend multiple hours in Tableau copying the varchar(25) MonYr to a date and change all the formulas because I have already worked on solutions since Monday and have none and it seems a waste of time to continue down this rabbit hole.

Comment: The snippet above would take 06/22/2019 and return 06/01/2019. It would take 06/01/2019 and return 06/01/2019.  That sounds like what you're asking for .

Comment: Andrew's code works as expected and can be simplified to `trunc(rqst.admt_dt, 'mon')`